# ng-repeat elements' indexes changing on sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an HTML table with rows created using an ng-repeat and data using properties of objects in an object array. They are being sorted by a name column alphabetically. I have setup some simple editing using ng-show, ng-focus, and ng-blur, so that there is no need for a save button or something similar.

However, as I am editing the name column, if I type a first letter that would cause that row to be lower in the table, it sorts the table as I am still typing. I tried creating a "temp" object array, copying the original array into it, modifying the "temp" array when editing, then copying the temp array into the original array when editing is done. That didn't work; the same thing happened anyway.

After a little research, I learned that both the temp array and the original array were probably pointing to the same data, so I tried multiple ways of cloning the array. I finally got it to work...with one exception: when I edited the object to be sorted lower, it moved. When I tried to edit it again, it did all sorts of random, unexpected stuff.

After some diagnostics, I discovered that the indexes of the objects in the table (gotten from $index) were being changed when sorted. For example:

```
Table
-------------------------------------
|Name    |Age     |Phone   |Index   |
-------------------------------------
|George  |25      |928-7495|0       |
|John    |34      |342-0673|1       |
|Megan   |28      |834-1943|2       |
|Susan   |19      |274-8104|3       |
-------------------------------------
```

If I changed George to Tim, the index of that object becomes 3 also. All the other indexes stay the same. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and/or give me suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have no control over the sorting of the "original array" ? Is it done via a filter ? You need to provide some sample code so we can tell what's going on.

Comment: @Amine Yes, I have a filter because I have created the table so that I can click on the headers of each column to change the sorting.

Comment: Need some code to see how you are implementing it.

Comment: Any examples? This is my first question :)

Comment: @JFischer00 can you set up an example using plnkr.co? Without reviewing your specific implementation it's hard to help out.

Comment: Ok, so what do you guys want? The way I have it set up now would be quite complicated to make into an example. I have a single-page MEAN stack app, but my controllers are in separate files. So one ejs file, one html file, and three js files are necessary for this one page on my website.

Comment: How are you filtering? inside the ng-repeat? Where do you type in? a search bar? then use the filter? The point is everytime you change the array the ng-repeat will fire and redraw with a new $index.

Comment: When you click the headers of the table, it changes the filtering predicate to whichever header you click. If you click it again, it toggles the reverse.

Comment: The problem here is that you're sorting a table which contains controls which in turn have an impact on sorting. Of course the indexes will get updated, that's how it works : you change the model, the change is instantly propagated. What are you expecting exactly ? Do you want Angular to "wait a moment" while you type stuff ? Do you want the table to be sorted only when you press Enter ? If you're not going to post your code, at least describe the desired behaviour with great detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I just didn't realize that the indexes changed every time I changed the data or the sorting of the data. After adding the index as a property of my objects, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use the orderBy Angularjs filter with column sorts that reverse on click. The "a" tag in the "th" is what controls the behavior. I have this in a directive, which is recommended, but the code can be in a controller.

I use the Angularjs orderBy filter as they state.

```
$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)
// This is the order of properties in the code below that looks like this
// $scope.rows = angularSortBy( $scope.rows, columnName, toggleOrderDirection( columnName ));
```

Each column has a font-awesome multi-arrow toggle called

```
<i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
```

Where columns would be something like this...

```
$scope.columns = { columnOne: { label: 'Column One', orderDirection: true, selected: false },
    columnTwo: { label: 'Column Two', orderDirection: true, selected: false },
    columnThree: { label: 'Column Three', orderDirection: true, selected: true }};
```

and rows could be anything you wish...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sort By</th>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in columns">
      <a href="" ng-click="orderBy( key )">{{ value.label }}</a>
      <span ng-if="value.selected">
      (<i class="fa fa-sort"></i>) // font-awesome arrow font.
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">// stuff here</tr>


var angularSortBy = $filter( 'orderBy' ); // use Angular's built in filter to sort table.

$scope.orderBy = function( columnName ){
  resetAllSelectedStates(); // sets column.selected prop to false.
  setAsSelected( columnName, true );
  $scope.rows = angularSortBy( $scope.rows, columnName, toggleOrderDirection( columnName ));
}

function resetAllSelectedStates(){
  Object.keys( $scope.columns ).forEach( resetColumnPropertyToDefault );
}

function resetColumnPropertyToDefault( name ){
  $scope.columns[ name ].selected = false;
}

function setAsSelected( name ){
  $scope.columns[ name ].selected = true;
}

function toggleOrderDirection( name ){
    return $scope.columns[ name ].orderDirection = !$scope.columns[ name ].orderDirection;
}
```